# How can I comment out lines inisde json file?

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio

Some date is stored in a json file, how can I comment out some lines like below?

```
[
    {
        "id":"aaaa",
    //  "path": "xxxx",
        "path": "yyyy"
    },
   {
       "id":"bbbb",
       "path": "cccc"
    }
]
```

My IDE is Visual Studio.

Comment: JSON does not allow comments. There is simply no provision for comments in the syntax.

Comment: You can't comment json. You can decode the json into a native structure, REMOVE the unwanted bits, then re-encode to json, effectively deleting the unwated stuff.

Comment: [Note that the lack of comments has been controversial at times.](http://blog.getify.com/json-comments/)

Answer (score 1):

Is it an asp.net project (you mention you're using Visual Studio)? If so you could store the json data as a view and use server side commenting out, e.g. in razor:

```
@* "path": "yyyy", *@
```